# google app script copy values !=0 into new column

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

I am trying to copy cells with the value 0 into another cell. Can't seem to get the if statement to work.

```
function pushGeo() 
{
var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###')
var ss = ssA.getSheetByName('thissheet');
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  for(var row=2;row<=lastRow;row++)
  {
    if(ss.getRange('G'+row).getValue() != 0){
      var source = ss.getRange('G2:G'+lastRow); 
      var destination = ss.getRange('N2:N'+lastRow); 
      source.copyTo(destination); 
    }   
}
```

Right now it's copying all cells into the new column.

==
Ah, nevermind. I was silly with the range. Time to stop coding for the day.

```
function pushGeo() 
{
  for(var row=2;row<=lastRow;row++)
  {
    if(ss.getRange('G'+row).getValue() != 0){
      var source = ss.getRange('G'+row); 
      var destination = ss.getRange('N'+row); 
      source.copyTo(destination);
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, nevermind. I was silly with the range. Time to stop coding for the day.

```
function pushGeo() 
{
  for(var row=2;row<=lastRow;row++)
  {
    if(ss.getRange('G'+row).getValue() != 0){
      var source = ss.getRange('G'+row); 
      var destination = ss.getRange('N'+row); 
      source.copyTo(destination);
    }   
  }
```